# How to snoop a channel in asterisk api node.js

Tags: node.js, asterisk, asterisk-ari

I would like to be able to spy a channel with REST api. I found out there is a function for this objective. But i don't know how to implement it. Any help is apreciated

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use snoop from ari-client

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve the explanation, or just post it as a comment to the question).